# Mapping to base class using automapper

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I need to map from a source class to a destination base class with auto-mapper.

My scenario is as below.

```
class Source
{
    string FirstID { get; set; }
    string SecondID { get; set; }
}
```

Also my destination is as below

```
class DestinationBase
{
    string ID { get; set; }
}

class DestinationObject : DestinationBase
{
    string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

When I use automapper with the

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, DestinationObject>()
      .ForMember(d => d.ID, s => s.MapFrom(s.FirstID))
      .ForMember(d => d.ID, s => s.MapFrom(s.SecondID))
```

One of the ID  after mapping does not work. Please any idea why ? I have tried include but i guess I don't understand its use well enough.

Comment: Is this the actual code that you have in your project? The map is for `Destination` but you have shown `DestinationObject` and `DestinationBase`. Also `Map` is upper case and takes arguments; and I don't think there's a method called `ForMembers`.

Comment: This is not the code in my codebase but a scenario I am working with. I will edit it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the ID field in the destination object twice so the ID will be the value from s.SecondId.
What are you trying to accomplish with FirstID and SecondId in the destination object?

Comment: Thanks for the relply the source object is a flat structure while the destination object is more oop. The base class is used as a means of identity custom datatype and the id is the content. I am trying to get a unquie object foreach id in nom.automapper terms.

Comment: I don't know of a way to map from a single source to multiple destinations.  (It may be possible but I couldn't figure out how or find any examples).  It may be easier to roll your own if this is a one-off situation and the source object only has a few IDs you need to map.